# Divs not orderded next each other - bootstrap

Tags: css

I have the next blocks:

```
              <div class="block">

              </div>

              <div class="block">

              </div>
              <div class="block">

              </div>
              <div class="block">

              </div>
              <div class="block">

              </div>
```

and i wanted them to be one next each other, and when it comes to the wnd of the screen - make them down a row and continue.
But its doing just a big list of the same blocks.

Here is the class:

```
.coverw-block-welcome{
  float: left!important;
  display: inline!important;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px!important;
  background-color: #1b6d85;
  margin:5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px !important;
}
```

Comment: That class isn't applied to the div's, they have a different class called `block`

Comment: Where is your css for the `block` class?

Answer (score 1):

Actually your html class name and css class name are not same so css are not working for this html.

Please update your code:-

```css
.block {
 float: left!important;
 display: inline!important;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px!important;
 background-color: #1b6d85;
 margin: 5px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 4px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"> </div>
<div class="block"> </div>
<div class="block"> </div>
<div class="block"> </div>
<div class="block"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the working version of your code down here:

```css
.block { float: left!important; display: inline!important; height: 50px; width: 50px!important; background-color: #1b6d85; margin: 5px; margin-top: 15px; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px !important; }
```

```html
<div class="block">
test
</div>

<div class="block">
test
</div>
<div class="block">
test
</div>
<div class="block">
test
</div>
<div class="block">
test
</div>
```